# Sul piede di guerra!

Tags: word-usage, phrase-origin

*Essere/stare sul piede  di guerra* è un'espressione molto comune. Si usa soprattutto per far sapere che ci si sta preparando o si è pronti alla lotta.

Alcuni titoli dalla stampa recente:

- Pd sul piede di guerra. E Renzi vola da Obama.
- Il mondo della scuola sul piede di guerra contro la riforma del Governo.
- 730. Professionisti e caf sul piede di guerra.

Secondo [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sul%20piede%20di%20guerra&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csul%20piede%20di%20guerra%3B%2Cc0) l'espressione *sul piede di guerra* si è diffusa dalla fine del '700 e, sembra fosse usata già da allora in senso metaforico.

Facile pensare che l'origine sia di natura bellica, ma a cosa fa riferimento questo modo di dire? Perché di dice **"sul piede"** di guerra?

Comment: Per ora ho trovato che viene da un romanzo di Balzac - Cerco altre fonti e scrivo una risposta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Da quanto ho trovato, l'espressione deriva dal francese.

Il riferimento più indietro nel tempo è Le [Dictionnaire militaire : portatif, contenant tous les termes propres à la guerre](https://books.google.it/books?id=qI0NAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT393&dq=%22pied+de+guerre%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Jp8yVeaQOeeBywPGqoDgBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22pied%20de%20guerre%22&f=false) che, parlando di Centurie identifica tre modalità: sul piede di pace, sul piede di guerra e sul gran piede di guerra. Quando una centuria era messa sul piede di guerra, quindi mobilitata, cambiava la composizione delle compagnie, modificando il numero di soldati, ufficiali e sottufficiali (non entro nel dettaglio perché il mio francese del 1758 non è *à point*). In ogni caso si parla proprio di una riorganizzazione completa.

Anche dizionari e manuali militari italiani la usano dal [1760](https://books.google.it/books?id=MYbQY3LqMc4C&pg=PA13&dq=%22piede+di+guerra%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5aIyVdKEK4P6ygOr9IDoBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22piede%20di%20guerra%22&f=false).

In inglese compare più tardi ("[war footing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/war%20footing)"), che è riferito esclusivamente al caso bellico e non ha la valenza figurata, che invece ho trovato in Balzac, [Le Père Goriot](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pap%C3%A0_Goriot).

Non riesco a trovare PERCHÉ si dica "piede", ma suppongo che rappresenti la mobilitazione dell'esercito. Inoltre ho trovato un altro link che parla di Nativi d'America, ma senza fonti (e secondo me si sono confusi con "sentiero"...).

Anche se non è una vera e propria risposta, magari altri riusciranno a ricostruire l'etimologia da quello che ho trovato.

Comment: Non ci aiuta molto a ricostruire l’origine dell’espressione, ma il _Tommaseo-Bellini_, alla voce «[Piede](http://www.tommaseobellini.it/#/items/82634)» riporta il sostantivo _piede_ nella locuzione in esame al significato figurato di ‹stato, condizione›. Nel _Vocabolario degli Accademici della Crusca_ non v’è traccia della locuzione: un indizio in piú a favore dell’origine francese e settecentesca. Nessuna occorrenza nemmeno nel _corpus_ letterario di bibliotecaitaliana.it.